# My Dynamically created LinkButton don't behave like LinkButton created in aspx page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, updatepanel, linkbutton

I have created a LibkButton in my aspx page by below codes :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLikeComment1" runat="server" OnClick="LikeComment">
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o icon" runat="server" id="hrt1" style="cursor: pointer">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="0" ID="lblComment1" Font-Name="Arial"></asp:Label>
        </i>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
```

on this state controls work as expected and `LikeComment` event fires from aspx.cs page.

now i want to get all comments from database and i add each comment from aspx.cs page using `Controls.Add(new LiteralControl())`

```
CommentDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
@"<asp:UpdatePanel ID='UpdatePanel" + idcomment + @"' runat='server' >
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID='LinkButton" + idcomment + @"' runat='server' OnClick='Like'>
            <i class='fa fa-heart-o icon' runat='server' id='hrt" + idcomment + @"' style='cursor: pointer'>
            <asp:Label runat='server' Text='0' ID='lblComment" + idcomment + @"' Font-Name='Arial'></asp:Label>
        </i>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>   
</asp:UpdatePanel>"));
```

but in this state `LikeComment` event don't fire. 
Could you please help me to find the problem?

Comment: You are **not** adding a LinkButton to the page, but a string. You cannot create controls in code behind as a string and add them to the page and expect them to work. But whay you are doing with the Literal `CommentDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl` can also be done with other controls: `CommentDiv.Controls.Add(new LinkButton`

Comment: @vdwwd i will be happy if you have better solution.

Comment: I want to add a group of controls like <asp:updatePanel> , <i> and ... not only a LinkButton

Comment: There are tons of tutorials out there. https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=use+of+dynamic+controls+in+asp.net